# Laravel App keep executing the same query with every request

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

This query always keep executing with every request which effect the performance extensively

```
select * from `users` where `id` = ? limit 1'
```

I have a laravel app, I tried to monitor the executed queries by using DB:listen in AppServiceProvider like this

```
 public function boot(Request $request)
 {
    DB::listen(function ($query) {
        Log::debug(['query' => $query->sql]);
        Log::debug(['bindings' => $query->bindings]);
        Log::debug(['time' => $query->time]);
    });

    if (env('HTTPS_ENABLED',false)) {
        URL::forceScheme('https');
        $request->server->set('HTTPS', true);
    }
 }
```

Now in laravel.log file I got the same query with every request, sometimes the same query get executed multiple times with same request, which is an overkill to the performance

laravel.log results

```
[2020-10-19 07:39:31] local.DEBUG: array (
 'query' => 'select * from `users` where `id` = ? limit 1',
)  
[2020-10-19 07:39:31] local.DEBUG: array (
'bindings' => 
 array (
 0 => 1,
), 
[2020-10-19 07:39:31] local.DEBUG: array (
 'time' => 1205.1,
)
```

I tried to check the `auth()->id() auth()->user()` if they have any effect, the middlewares, but didn't manage to get from where in the codebase this query got executed, so could you please suggest me how to stop it without effecting the flow of the app, or at least from where this query got executed exactly so I stop it and use jwt maybe instead of requesting db to get users with every request.

Thank you.

Comment: what kind of performance issue are you facing? for every logged in user one query is required to run to fill up `auth()->user` model.

Comment: @s.wadhwa
I have a huge database, with every request the app keep calling database to fetch users  `select * from users where id  = ? limit 1` for every user, Imagine having million of users at same time 
and it's not just on login, I emphasize with every request i.e (click homepage, click contact page, click messages page, and so on...)




i checked auth()->user() that was not the problem all I got is `select * from users where id = ? limit 1` BUT I don't know which part of code execute this query I just know it's there with every request,

Comment: its the auth system looking the user up by their id

Comment: @lagbox
yeah we used JWT and got ride of the session, to enhance the performance, and I cannot change the situation tho, I wonder if there is a solution for this issue here, I tried to trace the issue and found  tymon/jwt-auth JWTGuard@user() it calls a method  $this->provider->retrieveById($payload['sub']); which causes all this